# Other alternative with form.io in React Native for Flutter

Tags: flutter, form.io

I worked with React-Native, which has the [form.io](https://form.io/) and I can control my form (layout, state, condition...) with the Form.io Dashboard. I found out and it doesn't have any plan for Flutter. Is there anything to replace it?

Thank you for your answer!

Comment: You can use From widget to build, state will be handled by  your widget state, and TextFormFiled's validation will handle your condition.  You can check [forms/validation](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/forms/validation) it is handy.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But it is not what I need. I need control form dynamic from a dashboard with the same form.io work